# Spring Web Flow 2.5.1.RELEASE with JSF2.2 flow not executed

Tags: jsf-2.2, spring-webflow, spring-web, spring-webflow-2, spring-faces

I am struggling with this issue for 5 days now and I don't see where to look for a solution. 
I upgraded a JSF application from 2.1 to 2.2 with Mojara 2.1.17 to 2.2.14, including Icefaces from 3.2.0 to 4.2.0.

I also upgraded Spring 3.2 to 5.1.2 and Spring Web Flow from 2.3.2.RELEASE to 2.5.1.RELEASE. The problem is, after the migration all Spring Web Flow are no longer invoked. When I click a button nothing happens. I take a look at the web console and every time I click on a button which should trigger the web-flow, I keep getting an `http 403` error.

This is a snipet of my configuration:

```
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
        <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
        <webflow:listener ref="icefacesFlowListener" />
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow:flow-executor>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>

<bean id="facesContextListener" 
    class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />

<faces:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" development="true" />

<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="**/*-flow.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

The faces-config.xml is simple with only:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
```

And the `web.xml`

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>flow/welcome</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>flowDispatchServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config />
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>flowDispatchServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/flow/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>flowDispatchServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>
        javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
    </resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

The main dependencies:

```
    <spring-integration.version>5.1.0.RELEASE</spring-integration.version>
    <spring-orm.version>5.1.2.RELEASE</spring-orm.version>
    <spring-security-cas-client.version>3.0.8.RELEASE</spring-security-cas-client.version>
    <spring-security.version>5.1.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <spring.version>5.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.webflow.version>2.5.1.RELEASE</spring.webflow.version>
    <spring-ws-core.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</spring-ws-core.version>
    <javax.faces.version>2.2.14</javax.faces.version>
    <icefaces-ace.version>4.2.0</icefaces-ace.version>
    <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
```

I use Tomcat 8.5.
And a simple flow for tests:

```
 <view-state id="start" view="welcome.xhtml">
    <transition on="test" to="testView" />
 </<view-state>
 <view-state id="testView" view="test.xhtml"/>
```

The button in `welcome.xhtml`:

```
<h:form id="testForm"> 
   ....
  <h:commandButton id="btnTest" class="button" value="Test" action="test"/>
</h:form>
```

`welcome.xhtml` is well rendered but clicking on the button, I get the `403 error`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Anyone to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the reason. Spring Security enables CSRF by default, which blocks `POST` request on my form. Disabled it solve the issue. I lost 5 days!!!!